How to update a table using variables Snowflake - translating TSQL to SnowSQL
I'm starting a project translating a large number of old T-SQL Codes to SnowSQL and have gotten a bit stuck on setting a variable that can be used as the default value when I update a column.
In the actual code I have multiple tables that I'm trying to update at once (and the code is re run on a regular basis) and hence the preference for a variable
In T-SQL I have:
USE XDatabase
GO;

DECLARE @YEAR NUMERIC;
DECLARE @MONTH NUMERIC;

SET @YEAR = 2024;
SET @MONTH = 3;

UPDATE [Table X]
SET [Month] = @MONTH WHERE [Month] IS NULL
UPDATE [Table X]
SET [Year] = @YEAR WHERE [Year] IS NULL;

UPDATE [Table Y]
SET [Month] = @MONTH WHERE [Month] IS NULL
UPDATE [Table Y]
SET [Year] = @YEAR WHERE [Year] IS NULL;

I've read the documentation for declare and when I run a simple version of the example using the alias and value I'd use in my real code I can get snowflake to return the expected value:
DECLARE
year number(38, 0) := 2024;
BEGIN
RETURN year;
END;

(Returns 2024)
But when I try to apply this to the T-SQL Code (just started with one variable for simplicity):
USE WAREHOUSE X;
USE ROLE Y;
USE ZDatabase;

DECLARE
YEAR NUMBER(38, 0) := 2024;
BEGIN
UPDATE "Table X"
SET "Year" = YEAR WHERE "Year" IS NULL;
END;

I end up with:
Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 5 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 18 (line 6)
invalid identifier 'YEAR' (line 6)
Judging by the test example working, the issue must be to do with the update rather than the declare - but the error refers to the line containing the declare so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot beyond this.
Does Snowflake have any rules about updating and using variables that I'm missing?
There's nothing obvious that I can see in the UPDATE documentation either.

Hi - have you read this section of the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding ?

Variables should be formatted with a leading colon as noted in the documentation link from NickW:
declare
    year number := 2024;
begin
    update x
        set year = :year
        where year is null;
end;

